# swift - Generic classes with inheritance

Tags: swift, generics

When I try to execute the code below, I get the following error

> error: cannot convert value of type 'X' to specified type
>   'X'

Doesn't swift support inheritance with generics? Is there a workaround for this?

```
class Parent{ }

class Child:Parent{ }

class X<T>{
    var name: String?
}

var test:X<Parent> = X<Child>() //Compiler Error
```

Comment: What is your end goal here? It is hard to come up with alternatives if it’s not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @DamiaanDufaux, exact context is a bit complex. But in short, I'm having a method which should be able to return either X<Parent> or X<Child>

Comment: Can't you use a protocol for your method? Create a new protocol `P`, make class `X<T>` conform to `P`. Then use `P` as return type for your method. You can then return X<Child> as well as X<Parent> from within your method.

Comment: I have no control over the class X. It's defined in a library

Comment: You can conform it via an extension `extension X: P {…}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, generics are *invariant*, e.g. any `X<A>` will never be assignable to `X<B>`, regardless of the inheritence relationship between `A` and `B`.

Nevertheless, there are some exceptions to this rule, regarding Arrays and Optionals (and mabye some other types):

```
var array2:[Parent] = [Child]()
// same as:
var array1:Array<Parent> = Array<Child>()

var opt1:Parent? = Child()
// same as:
var opt2:Optional<Parent> = Optional<Child>(Child())
```

These will compile (since Swift 3) - but these a special cases treated by some hard-coded rules of the the compiler.

Comment: Is there any workaround to this? Maybe defining things differently?